# IdentityServer4 Offline Access and Refreshing Access Token

Tags: identityserver4

I have a fairly standard requirement for an oAuth2 service which allows the client to request the offline_access token and exchange the refresh token for an access token when it has expired.

Although this doesn't seem to be working at all. My client is integrating into Zapier. The zapier client is able to authenticate fine. However, after an hour the token seems to have expired BUT the client hasn't been able to retrieve a new token for whatever reason.

The following shows my persisted grants table showing that (I think) the refresh token has been accessed or created although the expiry time seems to be before the creation time??:

[image]

and my client looks like this - details extracted:

[image]

Only another thing in the Identityserver4 logs is the following:

[image]

I'm not sure why this could be the case?

UPDATE

Zapier definitely reach out and do the refresh:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The refresh of the access token is not something that you can assume is handled automatically for you.

Depending on the client implementation, it might be up to you to do the refresh of the token manually and sometimes it's handled automatically.

It's up to you to adjust the lifetime of your tokens and you can configure them by setting these values:

```cs
public int IdentityTokenLifetime { get; set; } = 300;               //5 minutes
public int AccessTokenLifetime { get; set; } = 3600;                //1 hour
public int AuthorizationCodeLifetime { get; set; } = 300;           //5 minutes
public int AbsoluteRefreshTokenLifetime { get; set; } = 2592000;    //30 days
public int SlidingRefreshTokenLifetime { get; set; } = 1296000;     //15 days
```

However, there's always a trade-off between convenience and security. Having an access token with long lifetime might be a security issue. Perhaps limit it to one week or two and have the user login again?

Comment: Just edited my question. It does reach out.

Im open to having it not have to use refresh tokens and just use an infinite access token. Is that possible?